# How to pass a dynamic value in a WHERE clause-function in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am trying to pass dynamic values in a WHERE clause-function in Laravel 5.1
but getting an `undefined variable` error.

Here is my code:

```
$bride_data = \DB::table('brides')->where('url', '=', $url)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
$bride_id=$bride_data[0]->bride_id;

$comments_data = \DB::table('comments')
    ->where('request_id', '=', $bridal_requests_data[0]->id)
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('sender_id', '=', $bride_id) // this value needs to be dynamic
              ->orWhere('receiver_id', '=', $bride_id); // this value needs to be dynamic
        })
        ->get();
```

As mentioned above, `$bride_id` is the value to be passed dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the bride_id to the closure like so:

```
$comments_data = \DB::table('comments')
            ->where('request_id', '=', $bridal_requests_data[0]->id)
            ->where(function($query) use ($bride_id)
            {
                $query->where('sender_id', '=', $bride_id)   // this value to be dynamic
                 ->orWhere('receiver_id', '=', $bride_id);   // this value to be dynamic
            })
            ->get();
```